# Как обновить запись в .NET Core Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, update, entity-framework-core

Пишется API приложение. Есть модель, которую я пытаюсь обновлять в БД:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Viewed { get; set; }
}
```

В поле Viewed хранится количество просмотров

И есть модель

```
public class PhotoForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

ну и экшн

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update([FromBody] PhotoForm photoForm) {
    var photo = _mapper.Map<Photo>(photoForm);
    _photoService.Update(photo);
    return Ok(photo);
}
```

и сервис

```
public Photo Update(Photo photo) {
    _context.Update(photo);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return photo;
}
```

Ну и моя проблема, при обновлении таким образом сбрасывается количество просмотров, ну и вообще все, чего нет в форме, например дата создания и иные поля, которые извне меняться не должны.

Что я делаю не так? Может надо просто искать запись по айдишнику и вручную переносить все значения? Или маппер не понял? Как это наиболее красиво делается? И в интернете везде обновляются какие-то тривиальные записи.

Answer (score 1):

кажется, строка вида

```
var photo = _mapper.Map<Photo>(photoForm);
```

мапает все поля, в том числе пустые, что потом сохранятеся в БД.

Решил путем поиска записи по Id, и уже в нее мапать обновления и сохранять:

```
var photo = _context.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == photoDto.Id);

_mapper.Map(photoDto, photo);
_context.SaveChanges();
```